# Getting ORA-46212 while trying to create ACL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, acl

For an assignment I need to make calls to a webservice using PL/SQL, so I wanted to start by creating ACL using `DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL` when I try this with my "normal" user it doesn't even recognize `DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN` and when I try to use it with the system user I get `XS entity with this name already exists` (ORA-46212).

The code I'm using is the following:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl         => 'www.xml',
                                    description => 'WWW ACL',
                                    principal   => 'CLOCKGEAR',
                                    is_grant    => true,
                                    privilege   => 'connect');

  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl       => 'www.xml',
                                       principal => 'CLOCKGEAR',
                                       is_grant  => true,
                                       privilege => 'resolve');

  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => 'www.xml',
                                    host => 'wsf.cdyne.com');
END;
/
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I hope that someone can help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Just wanted to mention this is a local oracle DB(Version 12.2.0) in case it could be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
  host => 'wsf.cdyne.com',
  ace  =>  xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect', 'resolve'),
                       principal_name => 'CLOCKGEAR',
                       principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
```

Oracle 12c has changed approach to acl. All method use in you code are deprecated. Try now approach.

Check these links.

[Example](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-enhancements-12cr1)

[XS_ACL Package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/DBFSG/XS_ACL-package.htm#DBFSG99328)

[Security Packages Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBFSG/plsql_pkg.htm)